# Display result of a operation as a choice button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, display

Is there a way to display the result of this operation as a button to choice?

```
var number = prompt("Enter a random number");
var number = number % 4;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var number = prompt("Enter a random number");
number = number % 4;
$('body').append('<button>' +number+ '</button>');
```

*Note that you must not re-declare variable `number`, or you will wipe out the value that was there previously (i.e. what the user just typed-in).*

```js
var number = prompt("Enter a random number");
number = number % 4;
$('body').append('<button>' +number+ '</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you're trying to achieve, you could do something like this:

```js
makeButton();

function makeButton() {
  var number = prompt("Enter a random number");
  var btnEl;

  if (number) {
    if (isNaN(number)) {
      console.log('The input is not a number');
      return;
    }
    number = number % 4;
    btnEl = document.createElement('input');
    btnEl.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    btnEl.setAttribute('value', number);
    btnEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log(`This buttons value is: ${number}`);
    });

    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(btnEl);
    return;
  }

  console.log('A value is required!');
}
```